# IIS rewrite when URI ends in a GUID

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make an IIS rewrite rule, where if the URL *doesn't* end in a GUID, I look for an API key custom header and do a rewrite. I have tested the following and **it works fine without the second condition** (which means it can append the header if it exists no matter what the URI is), but the second condition itself is broke.

I have tested this regex and it seems to be working fine.

```
<rules>
        <rule name="SpecificRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_apikey}" pattern="^(.+)" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="([0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1})$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/{C:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

Comment: The logic you described requires multiple rules (and probably utilize the do-nothing action, and stopProcessing=false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{REQUEST_URI}` always start with a `/`, and the url never matches with a pattern like `([0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1})$)`, So you need to include leading slashes in the pattern.

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/([0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1})$" negate="true" />
```